# php cURL request to instsagram API creates page lag

Tags: php, api, curl, instagram

I am using cURL toaccess instagrams API on a webpage I am building. THe functionality works great, however, page load is sacrificed. For instance, consider this DOM structure:

- Header
- Article
- Instagram Photos (retrieved via cURL)
- Footer

When loading the page, the footer will not load until the instagram hotos have been fully loaded with cURL. Below is the cURL function that is being called:

```
function fetchData($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $result;
}

$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat={$lat}&lng={$lng}&distance={$distance}&access_token={$accessToken}");
$result = json_decode($result);
```

So after this function is run, then the rest of the DOM is displayed. If I move the function call below the footer, it does not work.

Is there anything I can do to load the entire webpage and have the cURL request setn on top of the loading site (not cause a lag or holdup)?

**UPDATE:** *Is the best solution to load it after the footer, and then append it to another area with js?*

Comment: use ajax call after page load?

Comment: I need to use PHP (not js), otherwise I would have used ajax. I need a server-side call, not client-side

Comment: From client side you should call your server to make API call and return result to the browser. Loading it after footer is not ideal solution, since it have to be inside body, thus you are preventing document do be completely loaded, scripts from running, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the result json into a file that is saved locally. You can make a cronjob that is called ever minute and update the locally cache file. This makes your page loading much more faster. The downside is that your cache is updating even when you don't have visitors and you have a delay of a minute in data from instagram.